# Eclipse Console not showing output

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output

I have written a simple class having an SOP statement for "Hello World". But the Eclipse console is not showing output.
I then wrote the same program in a previously created project and it worked fine. I am opening the Console as given below:

> Window->Show View->Console.

But it is not working. I am using j2ee project in the same workspace. Any idea? Please help. I am stuck because of this problem.

Comment: share screenshot of your problem that you are facing. How some can know what issue you having if they don't see it.

Comment: Check that the right main is executed. And that there is no redirection (`System.setOut...)`).

Comment: @ShaU Not yet.I am trying to resolve it.

Comment: you share screenshot? or any more details.

Comment: Closing the Console tab and reopening it with Window->Show View->Console might also help.

Answer (score 27):

Go to "Window > Reset Perspective", that will reset the window settings to default. Next, you might need to stop any running Java processes. I suggest you then click "Remove all Terminated Launches" and if the red "Terminate All" is still available click that as well

[image: Remove all Terminated Launches]

Comment: I reset perspective and open console.it shows me console with red button on.i also click on terminate all button.still i will not work.

Comment: Hey one more thing i am using j2ee project in workspace.so is it causing some problem??

Comment: Make sure that you're running `Demo1`. Also, please edit your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 4):

[working] I encountered the same problem, I tried with all the solutions provided above but it didn't work then I came to a solution which worked. Follow the following process to overcome the problem.

Right click on workspace provided by Eclipse --> Select "Run As" --> Java Application.

[image]

This will work definitely.

Answer (score 4):

I've lost the console only in the Java default perspective and I wasn't able to show it again by using **window > show view > console**.

What I did is the following :

1. **window > Perspective > reset perspective**
2. **window > show view > console**

and It appears now!!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the project structure should be as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your System.out.println("Hello World") is in **main** method with proper signature.

Ex:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. What helped in my case:

**Run** > **Run configurations** > **Common** > *uncheck* **Launch in background** (last tab all the way at the bottom).

Then it showed the error why the thing wouldnt start.

In my case: a project dependency to a project which I had closed.

See (rightclick) **Project** > **Build path** > **Configure build path**.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Helps on the top bar. then click on Check for Updates. And update whatever updates are generated for your IDE. Helps> Check for Updates > ....

Hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check you actually saved your file. Many of us forget to save the file and simply hit run.

Comment: Cant belevie this was the problem! LOL
Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go **Run** > **Run Configurations** > *Double Click* **Java Application** > **Main** > *Enter *path* to your **main*** > **Done**!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a new answer to an old question, please explain why your answer is different from the previous.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is possible that number of character console can accomodate is beyond capacity, so increase the buffer size of console.
windows>prefences>console -increase buffer size

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just figured out the solution. Just check your main method it would be

```
public void main(String[] args){
```

just change it to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using jre7. Changed to jdk 1.7 and Eclipse console started showing outputs again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just right click on console window and click **Terminate /Disconnect all**.
2. Run the class again
3. Done !!!

Answer (score -1):

If eclipse is not showing path,

Please click on RUN-> Run configuration->click on environment tab->click on New-> add a path variable as mingw_path(if compiler is mingw in case of c++ ) and set value as C:\MinGw\bin (please check ur mingw bin path then only set).

Comment: This question is not asking about how to add PATH. For future contributions, please try to ask for clarifications through comments, if the original question is not clear enough.